# CentOS 6.3: yum install ImageMagick, identify and convert don't work

Tags: imagemagick, centos-6

I ran "yum install ImageMagick" on our CentOS 6.3 server, which worked fine, but identify -version and convert don't work (-bash: /usr/local/bin/identify: No such file or directory).

I originally installed it through source based on ImageMagick.org's instructions (they said to do this if I didn't have a supported OS version, and theirs was only up to CentOS 5.8). That installed fine (though it was missing delegates so I figured it would be faster to just uninstall and try it through yum). I have no idea the proper way to fix this and I'm not sure if installing from source screwed something up. Do I just need to set paths or something?

Comment: I did notice that identify is in /usr/bin... not sure how to get it to point back to there for that. It should be checking both I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do a “hash -r” in your shell to clear the path cache.  Your shell keeps the path to previously used commands to avoid seeking directories endlessly; it's a good thing, but what you stumbled upon is one of the rare instances where that mechanism fails.